# Why is (1/90) = 0?

Tags: c#

I am working in Unity3D with `C#` and I get a weird result. Can anyone tell me why my code equals 0?

```
float A = 1 / 90;
```

Comment: What is the precision of `float`?

Comment: I can't seem to find any documentation on that but I gues I am looking wrong. Its not in the unity script reference...

Comment: I changed the tag because this has nothing to do with unity, that's plain c#. 1 and 90 are int. So the result is an int (zero) than converted to float in the assigment. use proper suffix if you need float

Comment: As in most C-derived languages, dividing an integer by an integer yields an integer result (truncated, not rounded -- so 4/5 is 0 too). If at least one of the operands is a floating-point constant (or cast to a floating-point type), then the result will be a floating point value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The literals `1` and `90` are interpreted as an `int`. So [integer division](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx) is used. After that the result is converted to a `float`.

In general C# will read all sequences (without decimal dot) of digits as an `int`. An `int` will be converted to a `float` **if necessary**. But before the assignment, that's not necessary. So all calculations in between are done as `int`s.

In other words, what you've written is:

```
float A = (float) ((int) 1)/((int) 90)
```

(made it explicit here, this is more or less what the compiler reads).

Now a division of two int's is processed such that it takes only the **integral** part into account. The integral part of `0.011111` is `0` thus zero.

If you however modify one of the literals to a floating point (`1f`, `1.0f`, `90f`,...) or both, this will work. Thus use one of these:

```
float A = 1/90.0f;
float A = 1.0f/90;
float A = 1.0f/90.0f;
```

In that case, floating point division will be performed. Which takes into account both parts.

etc.